# iOS Siri: How to add multiple items to Reminders?

Tags: ios, siri, reminders

Using Siri, adding items to a Reminders list can be done one-by-one by saying, "Hey Siri, add apples to the shopping list". Naively trying "Add apples and oranges to the shopping list" results in a single item, "apples and oranges", being added to the list.

**Is it possible to add multiple items with a single command?**

Comment: I just tried "peanut butter and almond butter" and Siri added 2 items. But when trying a couple other things, it does the one item thing described above… ‍♂️

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Siri can perform **only one action at a time.**

So to add five different items to a shopping list you need to activate Siri five times. The same is true for other actions like “wake me up at 6 and set a timer for five minutes”.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer, because at the time of writing, there seems to be no method to achieve what I wanted. Then again, we have an Apple event coming up later today, so, 

Answer (score 3):

I found that if you want to dictate multiple items on the list you have to say “new line” after each item. For example:
“add garlic (new line)
Tomatoes (new line)
Basil (new line)
To Chris’s grocery list in AnyList”

Comment: I haven't been able to confirm this so far, since I'm using German language Siri and I'm unsure how to say "new line"; I'll report back as soon as I can

Comment: I couldn't get it to work. Siri displays the line breaks as I dictate, but the result is a list item with all the individual words separated by a space, e.g. "apples bananas"

Comment: In previous iOS version I was able to add multiple items using mic button from keyboard (instead of typing). “new line” worked even if said in Czech. When talking it was shown as single item but trasformed into multiple items when confirmed. In the latest version 14.6 it does not work anymore - item stays multiline when confirmed. :-(

Answer (score 1):

I just tested on iOS 16.3, these works:

- Hey Siri, add to groceries list A and B and C.
- Hey Siri, add A and B and C to groceries list.